# unable to write to shared folder across the network

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

unable to write to shared folder across the network

The following error occurs

[image]

but i have set up the permissions for everyone to be able to read and write to it??

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set the proper share permissions for your shared Folder. 
By Default Server 2012 sets share permissions to **read** for *Everyone* so this may be the Problem.

In the screenshot you posted, there is also a Share tab. Please check whether the user you are accessing the share with has the proper permissions.

File System permissions and Windows share permissions add add and have to be set correctly.
Maybe [this](https://serverfault.com/q/787935/362661) gives some insight.

#### Edit:

To add something after your comments:

To access a shared ressource over the network you have to specify the path to said ressource. It is in the format `\\servername\sharename\`.

In your case the *Servername* is **jarrattserver** and the *sharename* (as seen in 3rd screenshot) is **runnerjp**.

You should be able to access your shared folder via `\\jarrattserver\runnerjp\` which should show you the content of `E:\shared folders\users\runnerjp`.

Additionaly, again , please check if your permissions are set appropriately.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking at my question. I have already addeded full access share for everyone.  (i have added the screenhsot in my question)

Comment: Is the path you are trying to access correct? In all of your screenshots the paths are different. First screenshot: `\\jarrattserver\e\shared folders\users`, second screenshot: you show ACL for drive `Y:\ ` (root of drive), third screenshot: `E:\shared folders\users\runnerjp`. In your third screenshot theres also the network location to access your folder. Did you actually try to access `\\jarrattserver\runnerjp` or did you try `\\jarrattserver\e\....`?